# Firebase Realtime Database - How to efficiently paginate and load data in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, pagination

I'm working on an Android app that uses Firebase Realtime Database to store and retrieve data. I'm currently facing a challenge with efficiently paginating and loading data. I want to implement a solution that allows me to load a limited amount of data at a time, and as the user scrolls or performs some action, load more data.

I've looked into Firebase documentation, but I'm still unsure about the best practices for implementing pagination in Firebase Realtime Database for Android. Should I use `limitToFirst` and `limitToLast` queries, or is there a better approach?

If anyone has experience or can provide guidance on implementing efficient pagination with Firebase Realtime Database in an Android app, I would greatly appreciate it. Code examples or links to relevant resources would be particularly helpful.

Comment: Pagination on the Firebase Realtime Database indeed relies on `limitToFirst`/`limitToLast` and `startAt`/`endAt` operations. It's been covered regularly before here, so I recommend checking out [those questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+Pagination+on+the+Firebase+Realtime+Database) or [search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=Pagination+on+the+Firebase+Realtime+Database+Android). If you get stuck on a specific implementation detail, post a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can have a look at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm currently facing a challenge with efficiently paginating and loading data.

Pagination represents the operation in which you load the data in smaller chunks. The fewer smaller objects you download in a chunk, the more efficient paging will be.

> I want to implement a solution that allows me to load a limited amount of data at a time, and as the user scrolls or performs some action, load more data.

This is what pagination does.

> Should I use `limitToFirst` and `limitToLast` queries, or is there a better approach?

As @FrankvanPuffelen already mentioned in his comment, yes, to implement pagination, you should definitely use `limitToFirst()`, `limitToLast()` and `startAt()`, `endAt()` calls.

> If anyone has experience or can provide guidance on implementing efficient pagination with Firebase Realtime Database in an Android app, I would greatly appreciate it.

You can use one of the solutions that exist in already provided answers, here on StackOverflow:

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=firebase+realtime+database+pagination+android

> Code examples or links to relevant resources would be particularly helpful.

Since you're asking for an Android solution, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-implement-pagination-in-realtime-database-using-jetpack-compose-bd49084c8fd4) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/RealtimeDatabasePaginationJetpackCompose).